# Could not connect to broker URL

Tags: jmeter, jms, performance-testing, activemq-artemis

I'm really new in using jMeter. I've found a lot of things about my problem, but I couldn't fix it. I got an error saying :

```
Response message: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I watched a lot of videos and read documentations, but why I can't connect to it, I don't get it. I'm using JMS Subscriber. This is what I use:

```
Initial Context Factory - org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
Provider URL - tcp://localhost:61616
Connection Factory - ConnectionFactory
Destination - Data
```

And I use the authorization with my user and password.

Really sorry if my question is a duplicate question, but with a similar questions there are a lot of thing I didn't get it.

Comment: Do you have an ActiveMQ broker running on the same machine as JMeter?

Comment: I think that I have not running ActiveMQ broker. I need to configure it ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/1JSPiM5 , I am just connecting to this with my user and password. When I try to change localhost to the IP what I use to connect to ActiveMQ it says : Cannot send, channel has already failed.

Comment: If you want to connect to a broker running at localhost:61616 then a broker actually needs to be running and listening on localhost:61616. Your image doesn't indicate where the broker is listening. Do you have logs from the broker which indicate where it's actually listening?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I don't know much details, f.e what broker is and where should i see the logs.

Comment: I have to ask...If you don't know what a broker is why are you trying to connect to it from JMeter? The broker logs will be in the {{logs}} directory wherever your running the broker.

Comment: In the URL I type 10.20.2.23:8161/console/login and it takes me to the console management

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189399/discussion-between-justin-bertram-and-brithwulf).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your artemis on localhost to make it connect to

```
tcp://localhost:61616
```

In addition there is a convention on appending destination with jmeter script.
if you are sending to a

```
queue - dynamicQueues/{yourQueueName}
topic - dynamicTopics/{yourTopicName}
```